# Why does vmt hooking not work with instance member in the following case?

Tags: function-hooking, hooking

**Why does the function not get hooked when called with instance member obj.myFunc() ?**

```
class Myclass
{

public:
    virtual void myFunc() = 0;

};
class Derived : public Myclass
{
public:
    void myFunc()
    {
        std::cout << "Actual method is called" << std::endl;
    }
};

    void __fastcall hk_myFunc(void* thisPtr, int edx)
    {
        std::cout << "Hooked method is called" << std::endl;
    }

typedef void(__thiscall *fPtr)();

int main()
{
    Derived* ptr = new Derived();
    ptr->myFunc();// Output : Actual method is called.
    void** vTPtr = *(reinterpret_cast<void ***>(ptr));
    DWORD oldProtection;
    VirtualProtect(vTPtr, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
    *vTPtr = reinterpret_cast<fPtr>(&hk_myFunc);
    VirtualProtect(vTPtr, 4, oldProtection, 0);
    ptr->myFunc(); //Output: Hooked method is called
    Derived obj = *ptr;
    obj.myFunc(); // Output : Actual method is called. Why ??
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the output and looking at the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you reference this object with a new pointer.

```
Derived obj = *ptr;
```

This actually creates a new object utilizing the data of the old object. Yay! C++!

[image: IDA Decompilation]

In line 27 you can see that a new object is generated by calling a constructor. If you have a look at the disassembly, you'll see the vtable is not used for the function call. Hence you end up with the non-modified function.

[image: disassembly]

Btw, when you change the line referenced above to

```
(*ptr).myFunc();
```

The output works as expected